# ¿Cómo incluir una imagen dentro de un box?

Tags: css

Me gustaría incrustar una imagen dentro de un box.

Muestro el código y una imagen de cómo debería quedar ( específicamente la imagen que esta en el medio Color amarillo), estuve viendo sobre `position`, pero sigue sin quedarme.

Agradezco la atención!

```css
.box::after {
  content: ' ';
  border-top: 110vh solid #27032d;
  border-right: 10vw solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 453px;
  height: 624px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="logo.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
</div>
```

**IMAGEN**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1.- Comparte la imagen y 2.- Como quieres que quede?? centrado??

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar `flexbox` para centrar elementos dentro de un contenedor.

Modifiqué tu `CSS` para darle orientación a la imagen dentro del contenedor, si no es lo que necesitas, deja un comentario.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  /*Alinear de manera vertical*/
  justify-content: center;
  /*Alinear de manera horizontal*/
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #27032d;
  width: 453px;
  height: 624px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Bro! sí me funcionó, ¿Qué me recomendarías para dejar al final como tipo Diagonal, Barra inclinada,  / la parte del box?.

Comment: Puedes agregar un degradado como este `background: linear-gradient(95deg, #27032d 90%, white 10%);` aunque creo que se verá pixelado. También puedes investigar un poco sobre fondos degradados con `SVG`.

Comment: Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, considera marcarla como respuesta aceptada